# onPress not working in React Native Flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

My onPress handler is not working when someone clicks on Flatlist item.

Video of this issue
https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZWGOUkZmDLPeKQOQJJzxnqFB8Q21X3acT7k

Here is the code:

---

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import { View, Text, Image, FlatList, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
 
 

import { TouchableNativeFeedback } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

import axios from 'axios';
 
export default function _AjaxApp() {

    const [postList, setPostList] = useState([]);
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);


    const loadData = (append = false) => {
        let url = "https://edristi.in/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=20&page=" + currentPage;
        setIsLoading(true);
        setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
        axios.get(url).then((r) => {
            if (append) {
                setPostList(postList.concat(r.data));
            } else {
                setPostList(r.data);
            }
            setIsLoading(false);
        }).catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        loadData();
    }, [])

    let Loader = <></>
    if (isLoading) {
        Loader = <ActivityIndicator></ActivityIndicator>
    }

    return (
        <View>
          <View style={{padding:20, backgroundColor:"#4342fe"}}>
          <Text style={{color:"white"}}>Edristi App</Text>
          </View>

            <FlatList
                data={postList}
                renderItem={({ item, index, separators }) => <PostCard  postList={postList} {...item} index={index} />}
                keyExtractor={r => r.id + "-" + Math.random().toString()}
                removeClippedSubviews={true}
                maxToRenderPerBatch={2}
                ListFooterComponent={Loader}
                onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
                onEndReached={() => {
                    loadData(true);
                }}
            />


        </View>
    );
}



class PostCard extends React.PureComponent {


    onPressHandler() {
        console.log("Clicked");
        alert("Clicked");
 
    }



    render() {

        let image = <></>
        if (this.props.jetpack_featured_media_url.trim() !== "") {
            image = <Image style={{ flex: 1 }} source={{
                //uri: this.props.featuredimage,
                uri: this.props.jetpack_featured_media_url,
            }} />
        }
        //  console.log(this.props.jetpack_featured_media_url);


        return <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={()=>{
          this.onPressHandler();
        }}>

            <View style={{ margin: 10 }}>
               
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 17, lineHeight: 23, fontWeight: "600" }}>{ this.props.title.rendered}</Text>
                    
              
            </View></TouchableNativeFeedback>

 
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you want to use touchable feedback native? why not just touchable opacity

Comment: you should try this :- import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native

Comment: Thanks. That fixed my issue. But can you please run the code with TouchableOpacity and let me know if you face the lag or onPress not firing while loading the data from API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to import 'TouchableNativeFeedback' from 'react-native' instead of 'react-native-gesture-handler'.

Comment: Working Now. Thanks

Comment: But when the code loads data from API some times it stops responding to touch events. Did you check that? This happens whenever app fetches data from API.

Comment: Once the loading from the API ends it returns to fire? Does the activity indicator appears while you are loading from the API?

Comment: Nop! But. It shows the activity indicator. Actually I have actual lagging issue in edristi app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobapper.edristi&hl=hi

Please instal it on your phone and you will experience that the onPress does not work while app loads the data either from API or from Async Storage.